# Как перевести значения всего столбца в 10-тичную систему счисления?

Tags: python, pandas

Есть число записанное в 36-ричной системе счисления `"7NFC5S"`, которое находится в DataFrame.

Как весь столбец перевести в 10-тичную систему?

Просто число перевести легко с помощью функцию `int(chislo,разрядность)`, а вот как весь столбец фрейма.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пример:

```
In [246]: df
Out[246]:
      num
0  7NFC5S
1       Z

In [247]: df["decimal"] = df["num"].map(lambda x: int(x, 36))

In [248]: df
Out[248]:
      num    decimal
0  7NFC5S  462610000
1       Z         35
```